# How do I return falsey values from a Scope Query in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Regarding Scope Queries, is it intended behavior that returning any `falsey` value will result in an `Eloquent\Builder` being returned?

If I return any `non-falsey` value (say a number, string, array, etc) it will return the actual value (be it a number, string, array, etc) but if I return false, 0, null it always returns an Eloquent\Builder.

Is there a way to work around this, and return the correct type when a `falsey` instead of a object of type builder?

**Abstracted Test Case**

*In Model*

```
class MyModel extends Eloquent
{
  public function scopeTestFalse{
    return 0;  
  }
  public function scopeTestTrue()
  {
    return 99;  
  }

}
```

*In Route*

```
var_dump(MyModel::scopeTestFalse()); // object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder)
var_dump(MyModel::scopeTestTrue()); // int(99)
```

Comment: have you declared those functions as `static` ? the above example works fine for me, using laravel 4.1 on PHP 5.3.27

Comment: They're not static. When you say it works fine, what does scopeTestFalse return?

Comment: `int(0)` the other one returns `int(99)`,
make sure to declare all functions static because Eloquent implements the __callStatic() function (which gets triggered whenever you try and access a static method that's not part of the class you are calling).

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Scopes aren't meant to be static. Also, you can drop the "scope" portion when calling them - part of Laravel's magic. IE: MyModel::testFalse(); If you aren't manipulating a relationship or query object however you might look at simply making these a function and not a scope - which bypasses some of the magic used to chain query objects.

Comment: @AbbaBryant This is the correct answer, scopes aren't meant to be static and should only act on relationships/queries. Please change your comment to an answer, and I will mark it correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scopes aren't meant to be static. Also, you can drop the "scope" portion when calling them - part of Laravel's magic. IE: MyModel::testFalse(); If you aren't manipulating a relationship or query object however you might look at simply making these a function and not a scope - which bypasses some of the magic used to chain query objects.